Ideas to fix bathroom door window frosting?
We bought a condo and the bathroom door frosting looks horrible. What would be the best way to fix this? Cover in wallpaper? Remove and start over? How? Patch over with a privacy window film? Open to any other suggestions as well!
Photos


The upper panes and at least one of the lowers appear to look like the frosting is a separate layer that has cracked and peeled. If so you can use a good razor stripper and peel the old frosting layer off:

(picture source Home Depot link not an endorsement)
Then cover with your desired treatment.
If the frost is etched in and therefore intrinsic to the glass, but is merely oiled over by years of dirt, then the glass may be cleanable.
Otherwise replacing the glass or the door may be necessary

Just in case OP does not know, you mean window paint stripper, not a bare blade.

It looks as if someone tried to remove the film already.  Any attempt to cover it will just show the poor surface.
You need to scrape off the old film and then it's your choice as to what to cover the glass with.
Another consideration is to replace the entire door.

It may also have been a frosting spray paint, and not film.
